# Use jQuery to reuse Header and Footer code in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a static web portal created using Twitter Bootsrap 3.

I want to avoid using the "Header" and "Footer" code in all my HTML5 pages.
I am aware that I can use server side PHP, JSP etc, to accomplish this using INCLUDE tag, but that involves requirement of a available server running - which is not feasible in my use case.

Can I accomplish the same using **"jQuery"**? I am not too much familiar with it, so looking for assistance.

Please assist me here. Thanks..

Below is my code:

--> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test PHP</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<?php include("includes/header.html");?>

<?php include("includes/navigation.html");?>

<div class="container-fluid">

 <!-- START Page Heading -->
 <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <a><h1 class="page-header">Home </h1></a>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="active">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home
                    </li>
                </ol>

                <div class="container">
                  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                    <h1>Sample Website</h1>                            
                    <div class="row">                              
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END Page Heading -->       
   </div>
   </div>

  <?php include("includes/footer.html");?>

  <!-- Script References -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

1) Navbar Header.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>Sample Website</strong></a>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

2) Navigation.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="index.html"><strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home active"></i> HOME</strong></a>
    <hr>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="nav-header"></li>
        <li><a href="overview.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></i><strong> Overview</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i><strong> About</strong></a></li>                
    </ul>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>                   
    <hr>

    <a><strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> VIEW 1 </strong></a>
    <hr>
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
        <li><a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i><strong> Type</strong></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1">Type1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="View1_desc.html">Description</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>                                  
                          <li class="dropdown-submenu">                                             
                            <!-- <li role="menu" class="dropdown-header">Schema Type</li> -->
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a tabindex="-1">Inner view1</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <li><a href="Innerview1_about.html">About</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a tabindex="-1">Detail</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="detail1.html">Detail 1</a></li>
                                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="detail2.html">Detail 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a tabindex="-1">Type2/a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <li><a href="type2desc.html">Description</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a tabindex="-1">Inner view 2</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="idetail1.html">Detail 1</a></li>
                                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="idetail2.html">Detail 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                    </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>         
    </ul>

    <hr>            
   </div>          
   </div>
```

3) Footer.html

```
 <footer class="row">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4 col-md-4 col-md-push-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4 col-xs-12">
     <div class="text-center">
       <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 <a href="http://www.banes.com" title="Banes">
          <strong>Banes Ltd.</strong></a>
        </p>
     </div>
    </div>        
   </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have this code:

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

If you want to load something into this div, you can call the `load` function.

```
$('#myDiv').load('path_to_your_html/name_of_your_html.html')
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I either use $.load() or $.get() ... Just be aware that the $.load() method will strip out any script tags .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying, if it works out!

Comment: Was it ok or do you want more help? @user5139558